# Automapper not working on nested objects

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I currently working with .net core 2.1 and try to use automapper for nested objects to convert model to dto and dto to model. When every field is mapped correctly issue appears with relationship mapping.

Models

```
public class DropdownValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }
    public Property Property { get; set; }
}

public class Property
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ValueTypes ValueType { get; set; }
    public InputTypes InputType { get; set; }
    public List<DropdownValue> DropdownValues { get; set; }
}
```

Dtos

```
public class DropdownValueDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public PropertyDto Property { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public InputTypes InputType { get; set; }
    public ValueTypes ValueType { get; set; }
}
```

Mapper

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile() 
    {
        CreateMap<Property, PropertyDto>();
        CreateMap<DropdownValue, DropdownValueDto>();
    }
}
```

Usage in handler

```
_mapper.Map<List<Models.DropdownValue>, List<DropdownValueDto>>(dropdownValues)
```

Comment: Which properties aren't being mapped?

Comment: only Property field in DropdownValueDto. Return null. Expect PropertyDto

Comment: Probably because the Property in the source is null.

Answer (score 0):

I always use **automapper** mapping tool in .net 4x framework projects but when i develop .net core projects, i always use and recommend **mapster** mapping tool. It is pretty fast and simple ! [Benchmark Results](https://brahimkamel.wordpress.com/2017/11/05/benchmark-mappers-in-net-core-2-0/) It also solves your problem. You can check the example usage where is below.

First create a mapper class.

```
public static class Mapper
{
    public static void CreateMap()
    {
        TypeAdapterConfig<Property, PropertyDto>
            .NewConfig();

        TypeAdapterConfig<DropdownValue, DropdownValueDto>
            .NewConfig();
    }
}
```

Initialize in startup

```
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // other stuffs

        // Mapping
        Mapper.CreateMap();
    }
```

Usage

```
dropdownValues.Adapt<List<Models.DropdownValue>, List<DropdownValueDto>>()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Models

public class DropdownValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }
    public Property Property { get; set; } = new Property();
}

public class Property
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ValueTypes ValueType { get; set; } = new ValueTypes();
    public InputTypes InputType { get; set; } = new InputTypes();
    public List<DropdownValue> DropdownValues { get; set; } = new List<DropdownValue>();
}
//Dtos

public class DropdownValueDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public PropertyDto Property { get; set; } = new PropertyDto();
}

public class PropertyDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public InputTypes InputType { get; set; } = new InputTypes();
    public ValueTypes ValueType { get; set; } = new ValueTypes();
}
```